# PHP - having a tough time splitting a string

Tags: php

I have a string like so:

```
$string = "Monday - Thursday: 1pm to 6pmFriday: By AppointmentSaturday &amp; Sunday: 12pm to 5pm";
```

I am looking to split this string so it looks like so:

```
[hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Monday - Thursday: 1pm to 6pm
                    [1] => Friday: By Appointment
                    [2] => Saturday &amp; Sunday: 12pm to 5pm
                )
```

I am not sure if this possible, but if it is that would be great :)

Comment: Is there at least a `\n` or something between 6pm and Friday?

Comment: Where does the content for the string come from? No way to delimit the input?

Comment: nope there is no `\n` between 6pm and Friday

Comment: Where did this string come from? Can you give more example? 

If this is the only string you want to convert, it would be much easier if you just edit it manually and not require an algorithm to do something simple.

Answer (score 0):

The only logical way I can see that could work is if you use a regular expression match; split around days of the week that don't have a whitespace character immediately preceding (so you don't catch 'Monday - Thursday' and 'Saturday & Sunday' as 4 different matches).

It doesn't seem like a very robust solution but you have an odd problem to deal with anyway.

So, something like (I don't think this will work but it should give you the right idea):

```
preg_match('([^ ]Monday|[^ ]Tuesday|[^ ]Wednesday)', $string, $matches);
```